# Xamarin.Forms Load different pages on ClickEvent on TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I am working on Xamarin.Forms and I have a situation where have to render 4 different (ContentPage) pages on Tabs.So I'm using TabbedPage and adding different paged to parent page. Now the issue is when I come to tabbedpage all 4 pages are getting renderd on different tabs. Is there any way so that I can see 4 tabs but when a particular tab is clicked at the time of click event it should load page dynamically.

```
Page_1 = new Page_1() { Title = "Page_1" , Icon="icon_1.png"};
Page_2 = new Page_2() { Title = "Page_2", Icon="icon_2png"};
Page_3 = new Page_3() { Title = "Page_3", Icon="icon_3.png"};
Page_4 = new Page_4() { Title = "page_4, Icon="icon_4.png"};

Children.Add(Page_1);
Children.Add(Page_2);
Children.Add(Page_3);
Children.Add(Page_4);
```

I want to load all pages dynamically.Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

In your content page do

```
private bool _appeared = false;
public override void OnAppearing()
{
     base.OnAppearing();

     // To avoid repeating loading it. Remove if you want to refresh every time.
     if (!_appeared) 
     {
           // Load from here


        _appeared = true;
     }
}
```

This way they only load when the page is viewed